# Where to find cached files of previously visited web pages — Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser-cache, browser-history

I am trying to retrieve the HTML files from visited web pages while surfing with Google Chrome. It should have been on the hard disk at some point, so it can be visualized, but I do not know where to even start.

The problem is that I need to find some visited web pages that do not reside on the same URLs or are being changed after the moment of viewing. So the records in Chrome's history do not really help at all.

Answer (score 11):

## Files in your local cache

If you are lucky, then you might still find the sites in your cache. Depending on your operating system, Google Chrome stores your cache files in one of the following folders. You will need to fill in your user name where necessary.

- **Mac OS X:**
  `/Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/`
- **Windows XP:**
  `C:\Documents and Settings\[USERNAME]\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\`
- **Windows Vista:**
  `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\`
- **Windows 7/8:**
  `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache`

[(Source)](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/keN3Njx6gtM)

In order to look at the files, it is possible that you will have to add the file extensions yourself (`.html`, `.css`, etc.).

After a quick search, I also found this utility that lets you look at the files that are still in the cache more comfortably: **[ChromeCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html)**.

## Google Search Cache

If the website you are looking for is no longer in your local cache, the cache of Google (the search engine) might be of help. You can access a Google snapshot of the site by entering the URL of the site prefixed by `cache:` into the search engine, like this: [`cache:www.example.org`](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:www.example.org)

## Archive.org

If all else fails, do not forget to try **[Archive.org](http://www.archive.org)**. Similar to the Google Cache, the website you are looking for might be stored here. *Archive.org* also keeps older versions of the same website, while Google just keeps the newest one.

Comment: cache:... is brilliant, thank you. Github is down right now.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to locate html file that was cached in chrome, just has to follow below thread

**Files in your local cache**

Windows 7/8:
C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache

I found close to 2700 files in Cache directory with random names and no extension, i then used notepad++ to find a keyword in all the files under Cache directory, I was able to find the stuff i was looking for.

I hope this is helpful.
I express my gratitude to the person who posted "**Files in your local cache**"